# phpMyAdmin not working in Chrome though it works fine with Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, phpmyadmin

Recently, I updated phpMyAdmin to the latest version manually and now it shows a weird error when I try to login using Chrome. **It says:**

> Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin.

Though it is working fine with Firefox, I am more comfortable with Chrome and thus I am trying to log in using Chrome.

I have tried clearing all sort of history, cookies and site settings, but the problem persists.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing some extensions from my Google Chrome. Probably some of them are conflicting with PhpMyAdmin.